# Cannot read property "value" of undefined when selecting KeyboardDateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs

I'm using keyboard date time picker and this is the code I am trying to select starting and ending date:

**Switch**

```
const handleChange = (field, e, value) => {
let val = null
switch (field) {
   case "timeStart":
     val = DateUtil.toString(DateUtil.toUtc(new Date(e.target.value)))
     console.log("timeStart", e.target.value, val, DateUtil.toString(DateUtil.fromUtc(new Date(val))))
     setState({...state, timeStart: val})
     setErrorz({...errorz, timeStart: requiredValidation("Start Date", val)})
     break;           
        }
```

**This is how I call them**

```
 <FormControl fullWidth error={errorz.timeStart !== ""} className={classes.formControl}>
       <KeyboardDateTimePicker
       id="timeStart"
       value={DateUtil.toString(DateUtil.fromUtc(new Date(state.timeStart)))}
       onChange={(e) => handleChange('timeStart', e)}
       inputVariant="outlined"
       format={DateUtil.FORMAT}
       label={t('event.startdate')}
       error={errorz.timeStart !== ""}
       onError={console.log}
       InputLabelProps={{
       shrink: true
       }} />
```

But after I try to pick a starting or ending date, I get an error **Cannot read property "value" of undefined**.
If I delete `e.target.value` the date I select is returning back to completely something else, if I pick October 5th, it returns, April 17th.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9ROC.png]

Comment: It does seem that `handleChange` is passed an event argument. Are you sure `onChange` of `KeyboardDateTimePicker` passes an event object? Can you share `KeyboardDateTimePicker` component?

Comment: i have shared the component, isnt that one correct?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `KeyboardDateTimePicker` component code if that is a component of yours. If it is something you imported from a library can you share a link to that library so we can peek at its source code to see how it handles an `onChange` prop? From what you describe you aren't receiving an `onChange` event object.

Answer (score 0):

In React synthetic events are pooled and typically quickly nullified and returned to the pool for reuse. Since the console log isn't completely synchronous you should save the events value before using it in callbacks.

```
const { value } = e.target; // <-- save event value

...

switch (field) {
  case "timeStart":
    val = DateUtil.toString(DateUtil.toUtc(new Date(value))); // <-- use saved value
    console.log(
      "timeStart",
      value, // <-- use saved value
      val,
      DateUtil.toString(DateUtil.fromUtc(new Date(val))),
    );
    setState({ ...state, timeStart: val });
    setErrorz({ ...errorz, timeStart: requiredValidation("Start Date", val) });
    break;           
}
```

Comment: const handleChange = (field, e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
   }
I saved it uner my handleChange and get cannot destructure property "value" of "target" as it is undefined

Comment: @YaminOoh Does `KeyboardDateTimePicker` provide an event on it's `onChange` handler? Mind updating your question to include your entire `handleChange` callback function? If we could see the `KeyboardDateTimePicker` component as well that would be helpful.

Comment: Check it now please